# Angular Preselect/Initial Binding to Multi-Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind data from a web service and then use that data to pre-populate a form.  All form controls are binding correctly except for a single multi-select element.  If I manually select an option the model does update. Below is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('AdminVideosEditCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$routeParams',
    '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $http.get('/videos/' + $routeParams.videoId + '?embed=presenters').success(function(data) {
            $scope.video = data.data
            // Load providers
            $http.get('/providers').success(function(data) {
                $scope.providers = data.data;
                // Load Presenters
                $http.get('/presenters').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.presenters = data.data;
                });
            });
        });
    }
]);
```

Once the final request returns, my model looks like this (output via `{{ video | json }}`):

```
{   
    "id": "ca3ca05a-834e-47b1-aaa1-3dbe38338ca9",   
    "title": "Doloremque iure consequatur quam ea.",   
    "is_public": false,   
    "is_visible": true,   
    "url": "http://someurl.com/",   
    "provider_id": "1b4d18eb-d56c-41ae-9431-4c058a32d651",   
    "level_id": "38ed7286-da05-44b9-bfb9-e1278088d229",   
    "duration": "17:38",   
    "transcript_file": "rerum-sint-voluptatum.md",   
    "presenters": [
        {
            "id": "5111531d-5f2a-45f5-a0c4-4fa3027ff249",
            "first_name": "First",
            "last_name": "Last",
            "full_name": "First Last"
        }   
    ],   
    "provider": {
        "id": "1b4d18eb-d56c-41ae-9431-4c058a32d651",
        "title": "You Tube"   
    } 
}
```

Here is how the multi-select looks in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="presenters" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Presenters</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="presenters" ng-model="video.presenters" ng-options="presenter.full_name for ( id , presenter ) in presenters">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `select` element populates correctly, and I would expect for it to default with the "First Last" element selected, however nothing is selected.  I know my model is initialized correctly because if I manually select the element nothing in the model changes (if I select a different element it does, but still retains the same structure as it does on initial page load).

I tried adding a `$scope.$apply` call, and I also tried `$scope.$root.$eval()`, neither of which worked.

**Update**

The presenters model (containing all of the presenters) looks like this after it is fetched from the service (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
[
  {
    "id": "47b6e945-2d4b-44c2-b44b-adb96460864d",
    "first_name": "First",
    "last_name": "Last",
    "full_name": "First Last"
  },
  {
    "id": "5111531d-5f2a-45f5-a0c4-4fa3027ff249",
    "first_name": "One",
    "last_name": "Two",
    "full_name": "One Two"
  },
  {
    "id": "7cb1e44b-2806-4576-80b2-ae730ad356f7",
    "first_name": "Three",
    "last_name": "Four",
    "full_name": "Three Four"
  }
]
```

Comment: I set up a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/ej7Cv/. nothing seems to be coming up in the select box. Are you sure you get any data in there?

Comment: @dcodesmith yes, the presenters are actually loaded from the third `$http` call (and live in `$scope.presenters`, not `$scope.video.presenters`, those are the ones that are selected for the video)

Comment: Could you please update the fiddle to show it works, I've done half that for you already

Comment: fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ej7Cv/3/

Comment: link please, the link should be different now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Just put this at the bottom of your controller

```
$scope.video.presenters.forEach(function(obj, idx){
    $scope.presenters.forEach(function(presenter, jdx){
        if (obj.id === presenter.id) {
            $scope.video.presenters = [$scope.presenters[jdx]]
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/X92fT/)**

### More Robust Solution

This is more robust as you might want to preselect multiple options. This solution pushes each selected option into an array and then assigns it to `$scope.video.presenters` model

```
    var selectedOptions = [];

    $scope.video.presenters.forEach(function (obj, idx) {
    $scope.presenters.forEach(function (presenter, idj) {
        if (obj.id === presenter.id) {
            selectedOptions.push($scope.presenters[idj]);
            $scope.video.presenters = selectedOptions;
        }
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/HN2bT/)**

Note: Ideally you should be using the `id` key as the unique for the objects.
This solution assumes and only caters for preselecting one option.

Comment: without doing some kind of deferring, I don't think this will work since the ng-init will execute prior to my service call containing the presenters returns

Comment: Not sure this works, check: http://jsfiddle.net/ej7Cv/9/  I've changed the initial presenter to be the second entry, but the first one is the one that gets selected.

Comment: nevermind, I figured out the minor issue.. needed a second index parameter into the second foreach.  The unique identifier is the id parameter

Comment: also, changing the assignment to a push also supports multiple presenters, +1 and thanks for the help!